# Redirect php id Properly with .htaccess OpenLiteSpeed Server

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, openlitespeed

i am new to .htaccess usage and tried to learn through online resources but however i write it the rules negate each other and am having a hard time writing a good enough .htaccess file below is my current .htaccess file which works fine for some pages like removing extensions and rewriting subdomains please check below

```
## Flag for GoDaddy
Options +MultiViews

RewriteBase /

## Remove extensions
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

## Redirect from extensions to non-extensions
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

## Redirect Pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /post.php?ps=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ post-files.php?ps=$1 [L,QSA]

## Server Only

## Redirect from www - non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://$1/$1 [R=301,L]


## SSL Redirect
## RewriteEngine On
## RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ≠On
## RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

## Create Error Pages
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html

## Redirect non-existing pages to index.php
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Above is the .htaccess am currently using and i got it through tutorials from youtube it works good and redirects files.php to files only which am happy with but
as you can see above this line `RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /post.php?ps=$1` and the line below it are not passing through the ps but they show 404 page

i want the results to be  `domain.com/post-file-slug` to go to exactly file `domain.com/post-file.php?ps=post-slug-here` for rule `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ post-files.php?ps=$1 [L,QSA]`

and

`domain.com/post/post-slug-here` to go to exactly `domain.com/post.php?ps=post-slug-here` for rule
`RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /post.php?ps=$1`

I was working on this for 2 days now hopefully fix it soon. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ## Flag for GoDaddy
> Options +MultiViews
> ```

In what way is this a "flag for GoDaddy"? Enabling MultiViews will cause the `ps` URL parameter not to be passed to the `post.php` script. You need to ensure that MultiViews is disabled for the later rewrites to work as intended. ie.

```
Options -MultiViews
```

MultiViews (part of mod_negotiation) essentially enables extensionless URLs. It will result in a request for `/post/post-slug-here` to be "rewritten" to `/post.php/post-slug-here` *before* your mod_rewrite directive is processed, so it never matches and never rewrites the request to include the `ps` URL parameter.

> ```
> ## Remove extensions
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
>
> ## Redirect from extensions to non-extensions
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]
> ```

It is currently MultiViews that is allowing your extensionless URLs to work. The first *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) above is incorrect. It should be `!-f` (not a file), not `!=f` (does not equal "f" - always true). However, this is still "wrong", as you need to check that the `.php` file exists before rewriting the request. If you simply rewrite all requests that do not map to a file (which is what you are trying to do here) then the later rewrites to `post.php`, `post-files.php` and `index.php` will not be processed as intended.

The regex `\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?]` in the second *condition* is not strictly correct as it will result in a malformed redirect if `.php` occurs in the query string when it is omitted in the URL-path. eg. A request for `/foo?bar.php` would result in a redirect to `/foo?bar` when there should be no redirect at all in this instance. The regex needs to capture the URL-path only, so change the subpattern `(.+?)` to `([^?]+)` instead.

These two rules are also the wrong way round. The external redirect should be first. As a general rule, external redirects should always go before internal rewrites.

It should be like this instead:

```
## Remove extensions
 
## Redirect to remove ".php" extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# Rewrite to append ".php" extension if corresponding ".php" file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

You should already be linking to the file without the `.php` extension. The redirect to remove the `.php` extension is for SEO only when changing an existing URL structure.

No need to backslash-escape a literal dot when used inside a regex character class. The `NC` flag was superfluous here.

> ```
> ## Redirect Pages
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /post.php?ps=$1
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ post-files.php?ps=$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

`RewriteCond` directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows. So, the second rule above is processed *unconditionally* - is that the intention?

In fact, those two *condition* are probably superfluous. The regex would already appear to exclude actual files since the regex excludes dots. And do you need to be able to access filesystem directories directly?

The character class `[a-zA-Z0-9-/]` is "confusing". The last hyphen is seen as a literal hyphen (which is presumably the intention), but at first glance it can look like a range specifier (as used earlier in the character class). To avoid confusion when matching a literal hyphen inside a character class, either backslash-escape it, or move it to the first or last character in the character class. eg. `[a-zA-Z0-9/-]`.

You are also missing the `L` flag from the first rule. (You've included it on the second.) Do you also need the `QSA` flag? (ie. Are you expecting additional URL parameters on the initial request?)

Having revised the "extension removal" rules above, this does not matter so much, but these rules that rewrite the request to `post.php` and `post-files.php` should really be *above* the "extension removal" rules.

> ```
> ## Redirect from www - non-www
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://$1/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

This rule is incorrect and in the wrong place. Canonical redirects (www to non-www and HTTP to HTTPS) should generally be above other rules. As mentioned above, redirects before rewrites.

But this rule is also wholly incorrect. `$1` is a backreference to the first captured subpattern in the `RewriteRule`, so `http://$1/$1` will naturally result in a malformed redirect. The first backreference should be `%1` (to the last matched *CondPattern*) to match the requested hostname. Ordinarily, you should also be redirecting to HTTPS here, not HTTP. For example, the rule should read:

```
:
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `^` and `$` surrounding the `RewriteRule` *pattern* are superfluous since regex is greedy by default.

> ```
> ## SSL Redirect
> ## RewriteEngine On
> ## RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ≠On
> ## RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
> ```

Although commented out, it is also incorrect. It needs to go before the other rewrites. It should go at the top of the file if implementing HSTS *or* after the www to non-www redirect if not (and minimising the number of redirects).

The *CondPattern* in the preceding *condition* should be `!on`, not `≠On` (which is wholly invalid on two counts... `≠` is not valid and the comparison is case-sensitive. `HTTPS` will always be lowercase.)

You are also missing the `R=301` and `L` flags.

No need for a capturing group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, since this is not being used in the *substitution* string. `^` would suffice (and be more efficient) instead of `(.*)`.

> ```
> ## Create Error Pages
> ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
> ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
> ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html
> ```

For readability, you should define your custom error documents at the top of the file. (Technically, it doesn't matter.)

> ```
> ## Redirect non-existing pages to index.php
> Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> ```

For readability you should define the `Options` together at the top of the file (with `-MultiViews`). For example:

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexex +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

(Disabling `Indexes` - auto-generated directory listings - is a good idea.)

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive. (Only the last instance of this directive does anything.) It is logical to place this rule near the top of the file, before your first mod_rewrite directive. (Although technically, the position of this directive in the file does not actually matter.)

*Aside:* You should be consistent in the prefix you use on your internal rewrites. On some rules you include the slash prefix (eg. `/post.php`), and on some you have omitted it (`post-files.php`). You have defined `RewriteBase /` (which isn't strictly required here as it happens) - `RewriteBase` only applies to relative substitution strings (ie. when the slash prefix is omitted).

---

**UPDATE:**

> also i have file i want to exclude like 404.php in root directory from how do i exclude somefiles from the redirect. when i sent ajax to backend php file it redirected to homepage and failed to retrieve data.

To exclude specific files you would add a rule like the following, *after* the canonical redirects:

```
# Exclude "/404.php" from stripping the ".php" extension
RewriteRule ^404\.php$ - [L]
```

Generally, once you go extensionless for `.php` files you should be extensionless *everywhere*. So, there should be no unexpected redirects. The redirect is really only for SEO.

With regards to your AJAX requests, if you are making POST requests, then you could simply exclude all POST requests from further processing. For example:

```
# Prevent further processing of POST requests to ".php" files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [L]
```

Alternatively (or as well as), if your AJAX requests are setting a custom HTTP request header then you can check for this as well.

---

### Summary

Bringing the above points together, it should look like this:

```
## Disable MultiViews and Indexes
Options -MultiViews -Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

## Create Error Pages
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

#### Canonical redirects

## SSL Redirect
## RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
## RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

## Redirect from www - non-www
## >>> CHANGE TO "HTTPS://"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#### Rewrite Pages

RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)$ post.php?ps=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)$ post-files.php?ps=$1 [QSA,L]

#### Exceptions

## Exclude "/404.php" from stripping the ".php" extension
RewriteRule ^404\.php$ - [L]

## Prevent further processing of POST requests to ".php" files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [L]

#### Remove extensions

## Redirect to remove ".php" extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

## Rewrite to append ".php" extension if corresponding ".php" file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]

## Redirect non-existing pages to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks i watched from youtube that Options +MultiViews is for Godaddy hosting without adding it your .htaccess hosted in godaddy servers will not work,

Comment: also i have file i want to exclude like 404.php in root directory from how do i exclude somefiles from the redirect.   when i sent ajax to backend php file it redirected to homepage and failed to retrieve data. Please add it in your answer above

Comment: @ZackSnyder I would be interested to see that YT video regarding MultiViews/GoDaddy. (But that is nonsense/misinformation.) I've updated my answer with regards to making exceptions and AJAX requests.

Comment: Thanks so much this really helped me alot. i mean i have been jumping here and there but there is no proper guide on how to write, rules and structure of .htaccess Thanks alot,

Comment: also here is the link to the youtube video that said Add flag on godaddy hosting > it should be around 10:46 in the video >>  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mD3jrHZ3gUw&t=1609s